# Colocando findViewById no fragmento

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, webview, android-webview

estou tentando colocar uma webView dentro de um fragmento que se refere a webView que coloquei dentro do xml para o fragment o findViewByIdmétodo só funciona se eu estender uma classe Activity. Existe alguma maneira de que eu possa usá-lo também no Fragment?

```
public class VideosFragment extends Fragment


{

private WebView webView;

public VideosFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.xp4);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.https://www.google.com.br/");
}

  }
```

O findViewById possui um erro que indica que o método é indefinido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra chamar o `webview` dentro do seu `fragment`, primeiro que o `webview` tem que estar no mesmo arquivo xml do fragmento. Dentro do método `onCreate` faça:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false);

    webView = view.findViewById(R.id.xp4);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.br/");

    return view;
}
```